# How to setup a wordpress backup in localhost?

Tags: wordpress, installation, backup

I have a database backup and entire site folder backup of a wordpress site. I want to setup it  in my localhost. These are the steps I followed.

1. Create a database
2. Import the database_backup.sql
3. Open the wp-config.php and edit the following details

> define( 'DB_NAME', 'contents_wp' );
>
> define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );
>
> define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );
>
> define( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1' );

But I cannot log in to the admin panel. It redirects to the live site. How to solve this? What I am doing wrong here?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the site URL : http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Answer (score 1):

```
Simple trick here

1>> Delete your wp-config.php file, so that it will ask you re create the file

2>> Give the details as the system asks, like your db name, user name, password and table prefix.

3>> Next set the site title and log in to the admin panel.

4>> After logging in to the admin panel go to the "settings" menu set the "site url" and "home url" over there.

5>> Then you are all set with the settings, you can see your site in the  system now

6>> You might need to change the image paths if required, for that build a query and run that for ex: 

update clc_postmeta set meta_value= REPLACE(meta_value,
'http://wp.raddyx.in/CLC-Wordpress', 'http://clc.com/~clc/') WHERE
meta_value LIKE '%http://wp.raddyx.in/CLC-Wordpress%';


7>> Atleast run this query for wp_posts and postmeta table
```

Answer (score 0):

For migrate Wordpress website You require to Edit information in `config.php` file, After that In your  Database table name "`wp_options`" Require to edit value in "`siteurl`" and "`home`"  fields.

1)) siteurl is url where to redirect our site, when we write url in browser.
2)) home is url , when we add url/wp-admin, then where to redirect.

See Screenshot.[image]